# Is it possible to pass uri dynamically to Swagger definition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to implement API Gateway with `DefinitionBody` based on Swagger definition. My case is that request should be pass to another API, and I'm using `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` for that. It's easy to do with static uri, but in this case uri is created dynamically and passed as query string.

Is it possible to use it in OpenAPI specification? My idea was like this, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
 x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
          type: 'HTTP'
          httpMethod: 'GET'
          uri: 'method.request.querystring.url'
          connectionType: 'INTERNET'
          passthroughBehavior: 'WHEN_NO_MATCH'
          responses:
            200:
              statusCode: '200'
              responseTemplates:
                application/json: ''
```

Comment: Hi. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i just created Lambda function for that case and pass ARN to swagger defintion